# Convert PDF files to linked HTML files

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

Does anyone know of a way to convert a PDF file to HTML files, 1 file per page? If the pages can be linked with each other, that is, page 10 contains links to pages 9 and 11, for easier browsing, would be great, but not necessary.

It could be a program, or an online service, both are fine, as long as i can convert the file as explained.

I did find some websites that can convert from PDF to HTML, but they output a single large HTML file that is unfit for memory-deprived phones, and even firefox on a PC chokes on it.

The PDF contains almost entirely of english text only.

Comment: I have used Zamzar to convert pdfs to many other formats other than HTML (it does carry out pdf to html) otherwise try from the answers below http://www.zamzar.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can use pdf2html. The following is an example:

```
pdftohtml -p -c -hidden filename.pdf filename.html
```

For more details you may consult [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftohtml).

There's a graphical version for Windows [here](http://guiguy.wminds.com/downloads/pdf2htmlgui/).

Comment: with default options, i got a single large HTML file, using the -c switch, i got what i wanted, thanks :)

Comment: OK. I added the `-c` option to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this free program from **Sourceforge**

http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/